# How to register event while angularjs finish rendering UI

Tags: angularjs

E.g.

```
function SomeCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.list = [...]

    $scope.click = function() {
        var newdata = $someservice.get()
        angular.forEach(newdata, function(v){
              $scope.list.push(v) 
        })
        //???
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="height:400" id="main">
   <div ng-repeat="row in list">
   ...
   </div>
</div>
```

My question is when I add data to `$scope.list`, how Can I get a notify while data is updated to UI because I want the main div always scrolling to bottom?

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
var module = angular.module('testApp', [])
   .directive('onFinishRender', function ($timeout) {
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
       link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        if (scope.$last === true) {
            $timeout(function () {
                scope.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');
            });
        }
    }
 }
});
```

Notice that I didn't use .ready() but rather wrapped it in a $timeout. $timeout makes sure it's executed when the ng-repeated elements have REALLY finished rendering (because the $timeout will execute at the end of the current digest cycle -- and it will also call $apply internally, unlike setTimeout). So after the ng-repeat has finished, we use $emit to emit an event to outer scopes (sibling and parent scopes).

And then in your controller, you can catch it with $on:

```
$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
    //you also get the actual event object
    //do stuff, execute functions -- whatever...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Ravi posted a great directive to listen ngRepeat finish rendering. In addition I would create another directive to autoscroll content on update. The whole code then would be something like this:

```
// +1 to Ravi
app.directive('onFinishRender', function($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');
                });
            }
        }
    }
});

// Scroll content on every ngRepeatFinished event
app.directive('autoScroll', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
                element[0].scrollTop = element[0].scrollHeight;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Use it in HTML:

```
<div id="main" auto-scroll>
   <div ng-repeat="row in list" on-finish-render>
       <p>{{row}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/C5xKv/