# How to know when the DOM has finished rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how to know when the DOM is ready, after en element is automatically generated in by AngularJS (in an `ng-repeat`).

In my case, I create a new row in a table (which is an `ng-repeat` on an array) and I would like **immediately** to *programmatically* trigger a `click` event on an element inside a row. It doesn't work hiwever, because at the moment the `click` is triggered, the DOM element has not yet been created by Angular.

What I would like to have is something (an event) that could tell me "*hey I've finished creating your DOM element, go on and do whatever you want with me*". I searched for something like that but didn't really find anything who could do just that.

[I created a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HTpzrglOg88Vcwq0ZiDs?p=preview) illustrating the problem.

Comment: So, you'd like to do what add_row_delayed_click() does, except without a delay?

Comment: I thought additions of elements occur on the same thread that created them, so it would have been instant.  Can you confirm it is not a security issue regarding the activation of a file type input?

Comment: @Samuel Bolduc Where exactly are you programmatically invoking the click? That is not evident in the code you shared.

Comment: @edwin, in all 3 scope functions, I call a `click` method on a jQuery element, this is where I programmatically invoke the clicks

Comment: in this sort of case i use ng-init attribute where you can call a function ng-init="doSomething()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with the $timeout, but you don't need a long delay.
Angular needs a chance to update the DOM. By calling $timeout with no second parameter, you can basically say "Do this as soon as the current thread of work is done", so it'll run as soon as Angular is done modifying the DOM.

```
$scope.add_row = function() {
  $scope.table_rows.push({text: 'blabla'});
  var row = '#row'+($scope.table_rows.length-1)+' input';
  $timeout(function() {
    $(row).click();
  });
}
```

**EDIT**: That being said, this is probably a place where a directive would be better. Manipulating the DOM (even just firing click events) isn't something you're supposed to do in the controller. Here's another question to get you started: [How to register event while angularjs finish rendering UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783214/how-to-register-event-while-angularjs-finish-rendering-ui)

Comment: +1 use directives. I also tried the $timeout with no delay approach, but the click handler wasn't firing something like 1 in 15 times when I tested: http://plnkr.co/edit/AwhlGk0LD0cb2WBgcbWe?p=preview

Comment: Sorry - misfirings were because of stray errors thrown by the Plunker environment.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up wrapping it in a directive. Works like a charm! I'm not very familiar with those but I think it's never too late to learn!